# cakePHP authentication problems

Tags: php, cakephp, authentication, controller

I am unable to wrap my head around how the Auth component works in cakePHP. I am using 2.1

My login works perfectly, and from my understanding I can set the default component in the appController, which I did as listed below.

```
 // App controller:

 public $components = array(
    'Session',

    'Auth' => array(
        'loginAction' => array(
            'controller' => 'users',
            'action' => 'login',
        ),
        'authError' => "Your username and password is incorrect, please try again.",
        'authenticate' => array(
            'Form' => array(
                'scope' => array('User.user_status_id' => 1)
            )
        ),
        'redirect' => array("controller" => "users", "action" => "profile"),
        'loginRedirect' => array("controller" => "users", "action" => "profile")
    )
);

public function beforeFilter() {
    $this->Auth->allow("home");
   if($this->Auth->loggedIn() == true) {
       $this->set("user_name",$this->Auth->user("first_name")." ".$this->Auth->user("last_name"));
       $this->set("loggedIn",true);
       if($this->Auth->user("user_type_id") == 5) {
           $this->set("navigation","navigation_admin");
       } else {
           $this->set("navigation","navigation_loggedin");
       }
   } else {
       $this->set("loggedIn",false);
       $this->set("navigation","navigation_notloggedin");
   }

}
```

home is located /app/view/home.ctp, however, I cannot access the page without being logged in. Next I have 2 different user levels, normal and administrator. I want to limit certain actions in controllers based if you're an admin or not.

In my UserController I have example:

```
 public function beforeFilter() {
    parent::beforeFilter();
    $this->Auth->allow("login");
    if($this->Auth->user("user_type_id") != 5) {
        $this->Auth->allow("login","profile");
    }
}
```

But irrespective of the user type, everyone can view the actions.

In my pages controller I also have the following:

```
 public function beforeFilter() {
        parent::beforeFilter();
        $this->Auth->allow("*");
    }
```

But I have to be logged in to view any pages.

I am convinced I am doing something wrong, but I cannot wrap my head around what, any help?

Comment: app/view/home.ctp? You mean app/view/pages/home.ctp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, `home` is not an action on the controller, so `$this->Auth->allow("home");` wouldn't have an effect. `$this->Auth->allow("display");` would but would allow all pages to be seen (not sure if that's intended).

Secondly, you are using `$this->Auth->allow("*");` *after* you call the parent's beforeFilter, which means that `AppController::beforeFilter()` would treat it as if the user wasn't logged in, since it doesn't know what you've allowed after the fact.

Comment: This looks like the cause, isAllowed is checked after beforeFilter by auth by `$this->allowedActions == array('*') || in_array($action, array_map('strtolower', $allowedActions))` which in this case is neither because `$allowedActions` will look like `array('home', '*')` I presume.

Comment: @Jeremy: Thank you, this resolved my pages issue. I changed the $this->Auth->allow("display") in appcontroller, which worked like a charm to show all the pages. I however still find that in my users controller (as above) even with the if statement in place I cannot stop a normal user from accessing the add page, even if I use deny("add")

Comment: That's because Auth->allow has no affect after a user is logged in. The easiest way to accomplish that is to set Auth to authroize `Controller` and implement `isAuthorized()` method. See the book for an example.

Comment: Agree with @tigrang. For more complex authentication, implement `isAuthorized()`: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/blog-auth-example/auth.html#authorization-who-s-allowed-to-access-what